# Read value from dynamic form via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Help me please:
I have a dynamic part of a module (generated by php application), for example:

```
  <input type="text" class="attr" name="Input_0"/>
  <input type="text" class="attr" name="Input_1"/>
  ...
  <input type="text" class="attr" name="Input_n"/>
```

The value n is random (n> = 1). Obviously at the bottom of the form there's a submit button that confirms the completion of fields.

So, I need a procedure to read the modified values ​​of the input tag via jquery script that gives this output:

```
  Input_1 = value
  Input_5 = value
  ...
  Input_n = value
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Where do you want to output this value? Is this only for debugging purpose?

Comment: i use it for build a json object to send at another application, but my problem is how to read the values that change...

Comment: its possible to detect if it has changed from an empty value i.e "" to some value . but further detection isn't possible. If you're looking for just checking if it has changed from empty to a particular value. you could use the answer from @Tarek with a few modifications ,


`var $inputs = $('#form_id :input');

var values = {};

    $inputs.each(function() {

          if($(this).val() != ""){
            // this just prints to console, you can change this
            console.log(this.name+" = "+$(this).val());
          }

    });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is some sample code :

```
var $inputs = $('#form_id :input');

var values = {};
    $inputs.each(function() {
        values[this.name] = $(this).val();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try serializing the form data and looping through the inputs and their values:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) { // when we submit the form
    e.preventDefault();
    // loop through form data and print values
    var data = $.each($(this).serializeArray(), function(i, value) {
       console.log(value);    
    });
});
```

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kukiwon/ECz52/